# Proving entropy inequalities

Tags: entropy

I have two functions whose functional forms are of Shannon entropy type. The functions are:

$$f_1 = x \log x + (1-x)\log (1-x)+y \log y + (1-y)\log (1-y)$$
and
$$f_2 = xy \log (xy) + (1-xy)\log (1-xy).$$
Here both $x,y$ are less than 1.

**Question:** I want to know whether $f_2>f_1$ or $f_1>f_2$? Is there any inequality which says that. I tried some analytical calculation but couldn't succeed. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\left(B_t\right)_{t\in[0,1]}$ be a family of independent random variables with $B_t$ being a Bernoulli random variable of parameter $t$ for every $t\in[0,1]$.  Write $h(t)$ for the entropy (in the natural base $\text{e}$) $H\left(B_t\right)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.  Observe that $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is given by
$$h(t)=-t\,\ln(t)-(1-t)\,\ln(1-t)$$
for all $t\in(0,1)$, and $h(0)=h(1)=0$.

Now, fix $x,y\in[0,1]$.  First, note that
$$H\left(B_xB_y\big|B_x\right)=x\cdot H\left(B_y\right)+(1-x)\cdot H\left(B_0\right)=x\cdot h(y)+(1-x)\cdot h(0)=x\cdot h(y)\,.$$
Thus,
$$H\left(B_xB_y,B_x\right)=H\left(B_xB_y\big|B_x\right)+H\left(B_x\right)=x\cdot h(y)+h(x)\,.$$
On the other hand,
$$H\left(B_xB_y,B_x\right)=H\left(B_x\big|B_xB_y\right)+H\left(B_xB_y\right)\geq H\left(B_xB_y\right)=H\left(B_{xy}\right)=h(xy)\,.$$
Consequently,
$$h(xy)\leq x\cdot h(y)+h(x)\leq h(x)+h(y)\,.$$

The inequality $$h(xy)\leq h(x)+h(y)$$ for all $x,y\in[0,1]$ becomes an equality if and only if $x=1$, $y=1$, or $(x,y)=(0,0)$.  Observe that $f_1=-\big(h(x)+h(y)\big)$ and $f_2=-h(xy)$, up to a positive scalar multiple (if you use a different logarithmic base $b>1$).  Therefore, $f_1\leq f_2$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a doubt. I am not able to understand the equation $H(B_x B_y|B_x)=x.H(B_y) + (1-x).H(B_0)$. Can you please explain this in some more detail ?

Comment: From $$H\left(B_xB_y\big|B_x\right)=\text{Prob}\left(B_x=1\right)\,H\left(B_xB_y\big|B_x=1\right)+\text{Prob}\left(B_x=0\right)\,H\left(B_xB_y\big|B_x=0\right)\,,$$ show that $H\left(B_xB_y\big|B_x=1\right)=H\left(B_y\right)$ and $H\left(B_xB_y\big|B_x=0\right)=H\left(B_0\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

A direct calculation shows that $f_1<f_2$ as given in the picture, where the two surfaces represent $-f_1, -f_2$ respectively for $0<x,y<1$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with parameters $x$ and $y$ respectively. Observe that $-f_1(x,y)=H(A,B)$ the entropy of the pair $(A,B)$, while $-f_2(x,y)=H(A\land B)$ the entropy of the logical conjunction of $A$ and $B$. Clearly, $H(A,B)>H(A\land B)$ for $0<x,y<1$ (why?). Therefore, $f_2(x,y)>f_1(x,y)$ for $0<x,y<1$.